# Date Difference in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

`DATEDIFF(datepart,FromDate , Todate)`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dayofyear,'2008-08-07','2008-08-09') AS DiffDate
```

Result = 2 days

which date sql sever is exclude while calculating difference FromDate or Today ?
  Why it not be 3 days for 7,8 and 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, for yourself, you could remember that `DATEDIFF` views the range as *including the "from" date* and *excluding the "to" date*. So, in your case, only the 7th and the 8th are counted.

[Formally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189794.aspx), however, the logic is described to be this:

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified *datepart* boundaries crossed between the specified *startdate* and *enddate*.

How many `DAYOFYEAR` boundaries are there between `2008-08-07` and `2008-08-09`?

- `2008-08-07` -> `2008-08-08`
- `2008-08-08` -> `2008-08-09`

Two, as it happens. Hence the result you get.

Answer (score 1):

Because `9-7` is `2` in most decimal maths systems?

Comment: @Ilya It is an answer. DateDiff gives the answer 2 because 2 is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your are on the `7th`. How many days to you have to wait to be on the `9th`?

```
2
```